# How do I wrap a overflowed span in fixed div

Tags: html, css

If there is a fix-width div, inside is many fixed-width spans (or other container). How can I use CSS to achieve this style:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9iZc.jpg

rather than wrap text only, which has additional space in span after text, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3zk80y77/2/

```
.diagram  {
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     width: 30%;
     max-width: 30%;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     background-color:#605773;
}

.block {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}



<div class="diagram">
        <font class="block">aaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa axxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx</font>
        <span class="block">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</span>
        <span class="block">cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</span>
        <span class="block">dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</span>
        <span class="block">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</span>
        <span class="block">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example

```css
.diagram {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 30%;
  background-color: #605773;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.block {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px
}
```

```html
<div class="diagram">
  <font class="block">aaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa axxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx</font>
  <span class="block">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</span>
  <span class="block">cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</span>
  <span class="block">dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</span>
  <span class="block">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</span>
  <span class="block">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</span>
</div>
```

Just cut the `word-break: break-all;` from `.block` and paste it to `.diagram`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the CSS for `.diagram` as below. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zk80y77/8/)

```css
.diagram  {
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     width: 30%;
     max-width: 30%;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     background-color:#605773;
}

.block {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="diagram">
 <font class="block">aaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa axxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx</font>
 <span class="block">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</span>
 <span class="block">cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</span>
 <span class="block">dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</span>
 <span class="block">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</span>
 <span class="block">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Also thanks for your answer, while I can only choose one acceptance.